# Is there a "true or throw" or "non-null or throw" expression in C#?

Tags: c#, expression, throw

Given this working code:

```cs
if (!this.TryParse()) throw new Exception();
// or
if (this.Parse() == null) throw new Exception();
```

Since C# 7 knows **throw expressions** with `??` and `?:` already, I'm wondering if (or why not) there is a way to write this as a "true or throw" or "non-null or throw" statement in C#, similar to what other languages like JavaScript or PHP allow. This is what I tried:

```cs
// COMPILE ERROR:

this.TryParse() || throw new Exception();

this.Parse() ?? throw new Exception();

_ = this.TryParse() || throw new Exception();


// WORKS:

_ = this.TryParse() ? 0 : throw new Exception();

_ = this.Parse() ?? throw new Exception();
```

Especially, why does `_ = <obj> ?? <throw>` work but `_ = <bool> || <throw>` doesn't?

Why would I do this? Pure readability: I'd like to keep methods whose main purpose is DOING rather than TESTING clearly visible in the beginning of the line as call statements, and not conceal them in an if condition. Take PHP in contrast:

```php
mysql_connect(...)
    OR die();
```

Comment: `Exception` > `trigger_error` > `die`

Answer (score 3):

An extension method could be used for this scenario...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = false;

    a.OrThrow();
}


}
public static class ThrowExtension {
    public static void OrThrow(this bool b)
    {
        if(!b)
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`_ = <obj> ?? <throw>` works because in case the object is `null`, an exception is thrown instead of a value being returned. The type of the expression on the right side of `??` does not matter in this case.

`_ = <bool> || <throw>` does not work, because `||` can only be applied to two Booleans. The expression on the right side is not Boolean. (I would say, it is undefined.)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to use such syntax? Code should be as readable as possible, because while it is written once, it's often read potentially dozens of times.  If I see either of the the following:

```
if (!this.TryParse()) throw new Exception();
// or
if (this.Parse() == null) throw new Exception();
```

I automatically assume the programmer was confused. Why? Because two things:

1. A `TryParse` function returns a boolean and and populates an output parameter. It is used when you are totally OK with the input value being unparseable, but **don't want an exception.**  Example: [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)
2. A `Parse` function assumes the input is valid and returns a valid, non-null value, or throws an exception.  Throwing a new exception in this case is redundant, and potentially obfuscating of the actual issue. Example: [`int.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.8)

Keeping in mind that the example may be a poor one, let's look at a couple of alternatives.  First, you can write an extension method for this:

```
public static AssertNotNull(this object item) {
  if (item == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(“Object was null.”);
}
```

Thus, we have two alternative syntaxes:

1. Your syntax (`_ = this.TryParse() ? 0 : throw new Exception();`
2. My syntax:

```
    var val = this.TryParse();
    val.AssertNotNull();
```

Which is the easier of the two to read?  I left a comment on a colleague's peer review lately when he had used your syntax. In his case, he was performing an assignment on the right-hand side of the ternary if the first part of the ternary was non-null. BAD.

**Bottom line:** One should always write code as explicitly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is "because they didn't specify it that way". A summary about the throw expression can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#the-throw-expression). I think we can only guess why, but actually I think it makes sense. All of the new language features seem to conform to this one purpose: to be able to write code in a more functional approach. Let's see your parse example:

```
var parsed = Parse() ?? throw new Exception();
```

To write this without the throw expression, you either have to evaluate `Parse` twice, or to write down the `parsed` variable two times for a single purpose.

```
if (Parse() == null) throw new Exception();
var parsed = Parse();
```

and

```
var parsed = Parse();
// variable `parsed` can be null at this point
if (parsed == null) throw new Exception();
// variable `parsed` cannot be null anymore, the type of the variable is essentially mutated
```

So the first two examples are straightforward, writing `this.TryParse() || throw new Exception();` instead of `if (!this.TryParse()) throw new Exception();` would literally be the same thing in every aspects. So why introduce a new syntax for the same concept we already have one for? Remember Python's language design principles:

```
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
```

The last example is more tricky. The statement `var a_non_false = this.TryParse() || throw new Exception();` is syntactically very similar to `var a_non_null = this.Parse() ?? throw new Exception();`, however I argue there is a big difference. Variable `a_non_false` is essentially just a `true` constant (as if it were false we already have thrown an exception), so we could just replace `a_non_false` with `true` in the rest of the function, and get the same behavior.

As for the `_ =` part, I see it a different issue. I wonder why they didn't forbid the use of [discard variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) in such simple assignments. I would definitely avoid using them to replace classic flow control.

So in summary, at first these design decisions look arbitrary, but after a second thought it looks more well thought out.

Comment: I left a comment on a code review recently to the same effect as this answer. It seems many people don’t understand that code is written once, but read many times over.